# Error: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

Tags: ionic3, ionic4

my project return a error when i run "Ionic build"

> C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic> ionic build

[WARN] Detected locally installed Ionic CLI, but it's too old--using global CLI.

Running app-scripts build:

```
[18:12:23]  build dev started ...

[18:12:24]  clean started ...

[18:12:24]  clean finished in 15 ms

[18:12:24]  copy started ...

[18:12:27]  deeplinks started ...

[18:12:28]  deeplinks finished in 1.42 s

[18:12:28]  transpile started ...

There was an error in config file "C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\config\webpack.config.js". Using defaults instead.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\config\webpack.config.js:19:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.fillConfigDefaults (C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\config.js:316:26)
    at Object.getWebpackConfig (C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack.js:192:44)
    at Object.buildJsSourceMaps (C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\bundle.js:26:35)
[18:12:51]  typescript: ...ocuments/Ionic-Mobile/mobile-ionic/src/pages/otp-home/card/otp-card.component.ts, line: 11 
            Cannot find name 'require'.

      L10:  import { Clipboard } from '@ionic-native/clipboard';
      L11:  const vivus = require('vivus');

[18:12:51]  typescript: ...sers/OI403846/Documents/Ionic-Mobile/mobile-ionic/src/pages/otp-home/otp-home.ts, line: 24 
            Cannot find name 'require'.

      L24:  const hotp = require("otplib/hotp");
      L25:  const otplib = require("otplib");

[18:12:51]  typescript: ...sers/OI403846/Documents/Ionic-Mobile/mobile-ionic/src/pages/otp-home/otp-home.ts, line: 25 
            Cannot find name 'require'.

      L24:  const hotp = require("otplib/hotp");
      L25:  const otplib = require("otplib");
      L26:  const crypto = require("crypto");

[18:12:51]  typescript: ...sers/OI403846/Documents/Ionic-Mobile/mobile-ionic/src/pages/otp-home/otp-home.ts, line: 26 
            Cannot find name 'require'.

      L25:  const otplib = require("otplib");
      L26:  const crypto = require("crypto");

[18:12:51]  typescript error 
            Cannot find type definition file for 'highcharts'.

[18:12:51]  typescript error 
            Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
    at Object.escapeHtml (C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\helpers.js:253:10)
    at generateCodeBlock (C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\logger\logger-diagnostics.js:187:77)
    at generateDiagnosticHtml (C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\logger\logger-diagnostics.js:179:12)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.printDiagnostics (C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\logger\logger-diagnostics.js:15:39)
    at C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:158:34
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at transpileWorker (C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:64:12)
    at C:\Users\OI403846\Documents\Ionic-Mobile\mobile-ionic\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:109:82
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if we don't even have any snippet from the code in question? could you please provide at least what you have a question on?

Comment: which version of Ionic you are running? try solutions from this thread: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1516